# My iPhone says my Web App is untitled when it is?

Tags: css, iphone, html

When I try to add some of my web apps to my home screen on my iPhone 5 (ok on Android) the phone says the app is untitled even though it is. If I cancel and try again it works. It seems to happen the first time and around the seventh time (may happen more). Any ideas why and/or how to stop this from happening?

I’ve tried it on another iPhone 5 and an iPhone 4, and it does it on them too.

In my HTML index file I’m using the title tag as have heard phones will use this as the default title for the web app, which is fine by me.

```
<title>My Web App</title>
```

I’ve also tried using this line of code, but it hasn’t helped.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content=“This Is My Web App”>
```

Even if there is a way to stop it from happening the first time that would be great.

Thanks :)

Comment: could you make a snippet  of the rest of your code because there is nothing wrong here

Comment: @FadySadek thanks for the reply. I've put a snippet of the rest of the code [here](https://thimbleprojects.org/paul-k/185189/). It seems to be my Apple homescreen icons causing the problem, but I could be wrong about that :)

Comment: @FadySadek I think I've cracked it. I've put my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the home screen icons code fixed the problem.

It was this:

```
    <!-- Apple homescreen icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo.png"> <!-- 180×180px apple-touch-icon.png -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(57).png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(76).png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(120).png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(144).png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(152).png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(167).png">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> <!-- Apple hide Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"> <!-- Apple changing the status bar appearance -->

    <!-- Android homescreen icons -->
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(192).png"> <!-- highres-icon.png -->
    <link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(128).png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="96x96" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(96).png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(72).png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="48x48" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(48).png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="36x36" href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(36).png">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> <!-- Android install to the homescreen -->
```

It is now this:

```
    <!-- Apple and Andriod home screen icons -->
    <link href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(120).png" rel="apple-touch-icon" /> <!-- 120×120px apple-touch-icon.png -->
    <link href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(152).png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
    <link href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(167).png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" />
    <link href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" />
    <link href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(192).png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192" />
    <link href="images/HIN-Homescreen-Logo(128).png" rel="icon" sizes="128x128" />

    <!-- Apple hide Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <!-- Apple changing the status bar appearance -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Android add to the home screen -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

This webpage lead me to the answer: http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/adding-an-icon-for-iphone-ipad-android-to-your-website/

The problem seemed to be with the Apple icons. I removed some and changed the order. I didn't change any of the file names or where the files were/are.

The apple-mobile-web-app-title line of codes works every time now too.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="This Is My Web App">
```

It seems odd that the order of, and size of, images caused a problem with the web app title.

Any ideas why the original code caused my iPhone to say my web app is untitled when it is, please comment :)

Comment: Is there anything else we need to add for a solution? because I have added all the above tags still facing the issue of untitled in the PWA app