# Standalone PWA shows ◀Untitled instead of actual PWA name?

Tags: ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps, ios15

On iPhone running iOS 15.4.1, there seems to be an issue, where the back button to our PWA shows “◀Untitled” and not the actual PWA’s name or short name (see image below).

[image]
Same PWA on iOS 12.2 (left) and on iOS 15.4.1 (right) in dark mode after clicking on an Apple Maps link. Look at the back button in the URL bar.

Is there a way to open a link in Safari from a standalone PWA and show the app name "◀My PWA" in the back button instead of "◀Untitled"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in iOS versions 13.x+ which hopefully will be fixed in future updates.

1. https://medium.com/@firt/iphone-11-ipados-and-ios-13-for-pwas-and-web-development-5d5d9071cc49#64c1
2. https://firt.dev/ios-14.5/#bugs-and-missing-features
3. https://firt.dev/ios-15.4b#untitled-bug-still-there

Please try the fix suggested in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41708610/651676

Comment: Thanks Itai, I was aware of these links but thought maybe someone had figured out a way. I also had tried that suggestion earlier, but it didn't work for me either. Hopefully Apple fixes the issue or someone figures out a workaround.